# Lazy loading not working with 1 to 0 or 1 relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, relationship

I have the following table design.

[image]
As can be seen here, there is a one to many relationship, with the many on the EpisodePatient side.

Then, I have the following classes.

```
public class EpisodeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual EpisodePatientModel EpisodePatient { get; set; }
}
public class EpisodePatientModel
{
    public int EpisodePatientID { get; set; }
    public virtual EpisodeModel Episode { get; set; }
}
```

I am setting up the relationship, in Entity Framework, to be a one to 0 or many. The reason for this is, I am selecting all EpisodePatients from a View, and I want the Episode to be Lazy loaded when accessed.

This is how I am setting up my relationship.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EpisodePatientModel>().HasRequired(r => r.Episode).WithOptional(o => o.EpisodePatient);
```

I want this to act as a One to zero or many in my code, as an Episode will always have an EpisodePatient, and vice versa.

The problem I am facing is, when I load the EpisodePatient, and try to access the Episode linked item, it is always null, and Lazy loading does not occur.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

This is how I load the original EpisodePatient items.

```
this.DbContext.EpisodePatients.AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: Show query which load EpisodePatient.

Comment: @mwisnicki Please see my update

Comment: in the title you mentioned 1 to 0 or 1, but in the details you said _there is a one to many relationship, with the many on the EpisodePatient side_ ? if it is one to many you have to change it to be: `public virtual ICollection<EpisodePatientModel> EpisodePatient { get; set; }`

Comment: @Ziyad The problem is, when accessing the EpisodeModel, I only want to work with the current EpisodePatientModel it is linked to, not sit with an ICollection<EpisodePatientModel>.  Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I re-created your model but with data annotations like below and it workes fine:

```
public class EpisodeModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual EpisodePatientModel EpisodePatient { get; set; }
}

public class EpisodePatientModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Episode")]
    public int EpisodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual EpisodeModel Episode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I added Title and Name properties for testing purpose

Comment: Let me give this a try with fluent API. I am uncertain why you are setting the EpisodeId as Key, and foreign key?

Comment: since the relationship is 1-1 or 1-0, so only the main entity should have its own primary key (id), and the related entity primary key is the main entity primary key thats why we annotate it with [Key, ForeignKey],

Answer (score 0):

Try without `AsNoTracking()`, because if you use it your context is not tracking and you can't include more data if you need.

And try change to relation one to many.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EpisodePatientModel>().HasRequired<Episode>(s => s.Episode).WithMany(s => s.EpisodePatient);
```

Comment: Try with relationship one to many but still not using 'AsNoTracking()'.